Customizing Temporal Table DateTime mappings with EF Core
The datetime values in temporal tables are UTC. Is it possible to configure your DbContext class to apply a custom mapping to the sysstarttime/sysendtime columns? In this case I would simply want to convert them to the time zone that my clients are in, but I am interested if there is a configuration I can apply in just one spot to cover every entity. If not that then can I hook into the mapping process and apply it there? Thanks.
